# Passing an object to a class initializer

Tags: ruby

I started learning Ruby today and immediately dove into a question of how to pass an object to another class as its initializer. How do I pass a Name and Address to the initializer of a Person?

Here is my code:

```
class Name
    attr_accessor :first, :last
    def initialize (first, last)
        @first = first
        @last = last
        puts "created name"
    end

    def show ()
        puts first, last
    end
end

class Address
    attr_accessor :street, :city, :state
    def initialize (street, city, state)
        @street = street
        @city = city
        @state = state
        puts "Created addresss"
    end

    def show()
        puts street, city, state
    end
end

class Person 
    attr_accessor :name, :address
    def initialize (name, address)
        @name = name
        @address = address
    end

    def show()
        puts name
        puts addr
        puts "created person"
    end
end

name = Name.new("Sam", "Spade")
name.show()

addr =  Address.new("111 State St", "Albany",  "NY") 
addr.show()

person = Person.new (name, addr)
person.show()
```

The diagnostic I get is person.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
...erson = Person.new (name, addr)

It might appear that the creation of the person object is missing a "p", but the code shows the "p" as being present.

Comment: Remove the space between `new` and `(`.

Comment: A _syntax error_ means that Ruby can’t parse your code. It has nothing to do with initializers or object passing.

Comment: Method `show()` should use instance variables (with a `@`), otherwise you'll get an undefined error.

Comment: Tip: Run `ruby -w  nameofmyprogram.rb`. The `-w` causes ruby to warn you about suspicious things in your code (there are 4 of them in this one, after removing the bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a few bugs in your code.

```
class Name
    attr_accessor :first, :last
    def initialize (first, last)
        @first = first
        @last = last
        puts "created name"
    end

    def show()
        puts first, last
    end
end

class Address
    attr_accessor :street, :city, :state
    def initialize (street, city, state)
        @street = street
        @city = city
        @state = state
        puts "Created addresss"
    end

    def show()
        puts street, city, state
    end
end

class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :address
    def initialize (name, address)
        @name = name
        @address = address
    end

    def show()
        name.show
        address.show
        puts "created person"
    end
end

name = Name.new("Sam", "Spade")
name.show()

addr =  Address.new("111 State St", "Albany",  "NY")
addr.show()

person = Person.new(name, addr)
person.show()
```

1. You had an extra space between new and the params `Person.new (name, addr)`
2. In the person class the variable is called `address` not `addr`
3. I think instead of `puts`ing the objects in `Person#show` I'm guessing you wanted to call your `show` method which puts their attributes.

I think you got confused by the ellipses (...) in the `syntax error`. It was trying to simplify your code to the erroring part and it just so happened to cut off that p. The real issue is the space after `new` told the program to call the new method with no params passed in.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I got it to produce the correct output, but it also produced a whole bunch of error messages that don't make any sense to me. Do you get any of these messages when you run it?

Comment: I pasted the code I posted into a file called 'stack_overflow.rb'. Here is the output I get:


```
➜  tmp ruby stack_overflow.rb
created name
Sam
Spade
Created addresss
111 State St
Albany
NY
Sam
Spade
111 State St
Albany
NY
created person

```

No errors, and running on ruby-2.7.1.